# How to give a list as arguments to a function in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to learn elisp and emacs customization. I setq'ed a list of arguments to a variable. How do I go about passing this list to a function instead of just giving the arguments directly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`apply`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html#index-apply) function:

```
(apply 'function arglist)
```

For example:

```
(apply '+ '(1 2 3 4))
==> 10
```